# how to trim a month upto 3character in sql server 2008? eg:- april to apr

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have checked this query

```
select (datename(month, (getdate()))) + DATENAME(yyyy, getdate())
```

Result is `April2015`

but I want `APR2015`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()),3)) + DATENAME(yyyy, getdate())
```